# How to implement a logic to close open angle brackets `<` in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Imagine the following string "><<><" (it has brackets that are open but not closed)
my function needs to output: "<><<><>>" which would be closing the angle brackets.

I had success studying a way to check if the input is valid or not
but I did not find a way to close the brackets that were missing.

```
// learned from an article on medium.
let isMatchingBrackets = function(str) {
    const stack = [];
    const map = {
      '(': ')',
      '[': ']',
      '{': '}'
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      // If character is an opening brace add it to a stack
      if (str[i] === '(' || str[i] === '{' || str[i] === '[' ) {
        stack.push(str[i]);
      }
      // If that character is a closing brace, pop from the stack, which will also reduce the length of the stack each time a closing bracket is encountered.
      else {
        let last = stack.pop();

        //If the popped element from the stack, which is the last opening brace doesn’t match the corresponding closing brace in the map, then return false
        if (str[i] !== map[last]) {return false};
      }
    }
    // By the completion of the for loop after checking all the brackets of the str, at the end, if the stack is not empty then fail
    if (stack.length !== 0) {return false};

    return true;
}
```

- I tried keeping account of open brackets that were not closed but I didn't have success, I might have tried the wrong way
- I googled it but I didn't find anything useful so far

If you know the logic please explain below or point me the specific thing I need to study to be able to learn it. I am really intrigued by this problem.

Comment: Why should it output `<><<>><>` and not `<><<><>>`?

Comment: you're right! I'll edit the post thank you!

Comment: Sure, but my point wasn't to bring attention to your error. It was to encourage you to put your desired output into concrete, reproducible instructions. Once you're able to do that, and prove that those instructions work when applied to any valid input, then translating those instructions into a program should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be comfortable with the Stack data structure to be able to understand this, but from there it should be straightforward! Also, for the sake of being able to talk about this, I'll say that a clause is a left brace, followed by anything, followed by a right brace. So `<words>` is a clause, and `< stuff < inner > >` is also a clause. Note that clauses can contain nested clauses -- `< inner >` is a clause within a clause in the second example.

Now that we have a language to talk about this problem in, let's talk about the algorithm.

We're going to proceed through the string from left to right. Every time we see a left brace, we're "stepping into" a new clause. We only "leave" that clause when we hit a corresponding right brace. But how do we handle nested braces? Well, if we're in clause 1, and we hit a left brace, we are now in a new clause (we'll call it clause 2). When we hit a right brace, we don't want to leave clause 1, just clause 2. In fact, if you think about it, you'll realize that when we hit a right brace we are only ever leaving one clause -- the clauses it is nested inside still need to be closed.

The perfect data structure for this is the stack. We will push left braces onto the stack when we read them, and pop them from the stack when we read right braces. This will preserve the nested structure that we need -- if we nest clause 2 inside of clause 1, clause 2 will be above it on the stack, and must be popped before clause 1 can be closed.

So given this, what does the state of the stack at the end of processing mean? If the stack is empty, every clause was closed properly. If the stack still has items left, that means that there are some number of unclosed braces. It should suffice to pop each opening brace off of the stack and append its corresponding closing brace to the end of the string.

EXTRA NOTES:

If we ever try to pop something off of the stack and the stack is empty, then we have *too many* closing braces! You should also check that the thing you're popping is the corresponding opening brace, because you may have mismatched brace types (in your example, we are handling '(', '[', and '<', not just one brace type).

Also, this notion of stepping into and out of clauses may feel familiar -- it should! This is also exactly how control flow works with regards to calling functions -- and a stack is exactly how that control flow is managed!